# SonarQube - Java - Force local variables to be effectively final

Tags: java, sonarqube, final, rules, local-variables

I am using **SonarQube** and i can't find any rule for **Java** that would report reassignment of local variables (optionally also method parameters or class fields, but not in setters of course), or, in other words, force every local variable to be **effectively final**.

#### Non compilant example

```java
public Car createRedCar() {
  Car car = new Car();
  car.setColor(Color.RED);

  car = makeCool(car); // <- error, car variable was reassigned
  // do other irrelevant stuff with car, eg log, dispatch event or whatever
  return car;
}
```

#### Compilant example

```java
public Car createRedCar() {
  Car car = new Car();
  car.setColor(Color.RED);

  Car coolCar = makeCool(car); // <- it's ok, because all local variables are effectively final
  // do other irrelevant stuff with car, eg log, dispatch event or whatever
  return coolCar;
}
```

#### Another compilant example

```java
public Car createRedCar() {
  final Car car = new Car();
  car.setColor(Color.RED);

  final Car coolCar = makeCool(car); // <- it's also ok, but i don't want to force every variable to be final
  // do other irrelevant stuff with car, eg log, dispatch event or whatever
  return coolCar;
}
```

**I don't want to force every variable to have final keyword, just for them to be effectively final OR final.**

If no default rule for this is present i'm okay with using custom rules and / or plugins, or finally even write one, but someone probably already did this and this is why i'm posting here.

I am using sonarqube-7.4, and i am willing to update if it comes with the rule i want.

Comment: well i am not aware of any rule doing what you want, there is checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.FinalLocalVariableCheck and there is squid:S1226 which partially do what you want but not exactly :) - but i am not aware of such a rule

Comment: Thanks, `FinalLocalVariableCheck` is not really applicable to my case, but `squid:S1226` is definitely a step forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, i've developed a rule that does what i was asking for in the question. For now, it was tested only on **sonarqube-8.3.1**.

[link to the repo](https://github.com/kamilbeben/variable-reassignment-check).